# Get open ports as an array

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep, netstat

So, I'm using `netstat -lt` to get open ports. However, I'm not interested in certain values (like SSH or 22), so I want to be able to exclude them. I also want to get them as an array in bash. So far I have `netstat -lt | sed -r 's/tcp[^:]+://g' | cut -d' ' -f1` but they're not an array, nor am I excluding anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `($())` around your statement:

```
port=($(netstat -ltn | sed -rne '/^tcp/{/:(22|25)\>/d;s/.*:([0-9]+)\>.*/\1/p}'))
```

Filtering ports 22 and 25.

Comment: Doesn't work? I did an `echo $port` as the next line and all it printed out was 'Active'. Also, this doesn't have the ability to exclude certain values.

Comment: `echo ${port[@]}`  It is an array, as requested

Comment: @Andy Shulman, to print all array elements use "echo ${array[*]}"

Comment: The form `${array[*]}` compares to `${array[@]}`, as $* compares to $@

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `ss` command, which replaces `netstat`.

```
ss -atu | awk '{print $5}' | awk -F: '{print $NF}'
```

The `ss` command gives you all TCP and UDP ports on the local machine (the only sockets that would have ports). The first awk extracts the column containing the local address and port number. The second `awk` takes only the last field following a colon; this is necessary in case you have IPv6 sockets on your machine, whose IP address will also include colons.

Once you've done this, you can `grep` out the ports you don't want. Also, see the documentation referred to by the `ss` man page for information on filters, which may let you filter out unwanted sockets from the output of `ss`.

Comment: I was expecting to be able to reduce the two `awk` commands to one simple command, but the shortest I can come up with is: `ss -atu | awk '{ old=FS; FS=":"; $0=$5; print $NF; FS=old }'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=( `netstat -ltn --inet | sed -r -e '1,2d''s/tcp[^:]+://g' | cut -d' ' -f1 | sed -e '1,2d' | grep -v "22\|33\|25"` )
```

second sed command removes headers if your version of netstat prints such. I have "Active" and "Proto" as first two lines. Use grep to filter unwanted ports. add -n to netstat to see port numbers instead of names. --inet is to force ipv4, otherwise you may see IPv6 which may confuse your script.

btw not sure you need an array. usually arrays are needed only if you are going to work on a subset of values you have. If you work on all values there are simpler constructs but not sure what you're going to do.

Regards.

update: you can use a single sed command with two operations instead of two separate invocations:

```
sed -r -e '1,2d' -e 's/tcp[^:]+://g'
```